# How to vertically list all days of the month in Google Sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sequence

With [Populate a Full Month’s Dates Based on a Drop-down in Google Sheets](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/populate-a-full-months-dates-based-on-a-drop-down/) how to I was able to list all days of a month next to each other.

```
=TRANSPOSE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ArrayFormula(date($A$1;MONTH(A2&1);1)+transpose(COLUMN($C$1:$BK$1)-3));DAY(EOMONTH(date($A$1;MONTH(A2&1);1);0));1))
```

[image: Current situation]

What do I need to change in the current formula to list them below each other?

[image: Desired situation]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to take a wild guess and say Erase the word "transpose()"

```
=(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ArrayFormula(date($A$1;MONTH(A2&1);1)+transpose(COLUMN($C$1:$BK$1)-3));DAY(EOMONTH(date($A$1;MONTH(A2&1);1);0));1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the TRANSPOSE function invocation:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ArrayFormula(date($A$1;MONTH(A2&1);1)+transpose(COLUMN($C$1:$BK$1)-3));DAY(EOMONTH(date($A$1;MONTH(A2&1);1);0));1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works. I have selected lightweight mcgee answer because it was basically the same answer. Only he/she posted earlier.

Answer (score 1):

#### EDIT

(Following your comment[How to vertically list all days of the month in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66926979/how-to-vertically-list-all-days-of-the-month-in-google-sheets#comment118308920_66928094))

> I gave it a try but I got a Parse error.

ALWAYS CHECK YOUR LOCALE (when using copy/paste)

In your case you ONLY have to change `,` to `;`.

So the formulas will be

#### For Horizontal

```
=TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(A1&A2;0));1;A1&A2;1))
```

#### For Vertical

```
=SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(A1&A2;0));1;A1&A2;1)
```

Use twice and format accordingly.

---

**Original answer**.

Instead of that long formula try this one.

#### For Horizontal

```
=TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(A1&A2,0)),1,A1&A2,1))
```

#### For Vertical

```
=SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(A1&A2,0)),1,A1&A2,1)
```

Use twice and format accordingly.

[image]

Comment: I gave it a try but I got a Parse error. But thanks anyway for looking into this.

Comment: @Raoul The formula works fine. The issue is your locale. Check the edited answer.

Comment: You are right. I had to change the "," to ";". This is indeed a much easier and cleaner look. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Can you please also let me know how to populate the day next to the date. Like you did in the screenshot?

Comment: Sure. As said *"Use twice and format accordingly"*. That is : use the same formula in both cases, go to the menu, Format/Number/More formats/More date and number formats and use or create whatever your needs are.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. I appreciate you taking the time to help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

That`s great but the dates I am getting are not in a chronological order since their "code" is something like 44324 and they are order by it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31085153)